# Force `go get` and `go install` to use cache even if it's ancient

Tags: go, go-get, goinstall

Is there a flag for `go get` or `go install` to force those to use the cache, even if the cache is very old / ancient? We are using docker images / multi-stage build to cache deps, and those original files might be weeks or months old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`go.mod` may record concrete versions or commits you depend on. If you need old versions of your deps, state them explicitly in your `go.mod` and you get reproducible builds even if your dependencies evolve.

Use `go get foo@123456` if you need the `123456` commit of your `foo` dependency.

Use `go get foo@v0.1.2` if you need the `v0.1.2` version of your dependency. These will get recorded in `go.mod`, and no matter where / when you build your module, it will always use these versions.

For details, see [Go Wiki: Modules: How to Upgrade and Downgrade Dependencies](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#how-to-upgrade-and-downgrade-dependencies).